# How to pass a parameter when user clicks a link

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question regarding the parameter in `onclick`

I have

```
function testPro(){
   codes....
   codes....

    var test = 'init';  //the test can only be init here...

    link.href         = '#';
    link.innerHTML   += 'test value';
    link.onclick      = onClick;
    link.onmouseover  = onHover;
    link.onmouseout   = hoverOut;  
   codes....
}

function onHover(){
   alert(test);
}
```

I want to pass test variable when user `clicks` the button. I can't use `onHover(test)` becasue it gave me errors. How do I solve this issue?

Thanks so much

Comment: but if onHover takes a parameter , how will you assign this parameter ?

Comment: JavaScript variables have scope to the function in which they are created, or else they are global.  Since 'test' is defined in 'testPro', it is not visible in 'onHover'.  Also, when you say "it gave me errors", it would be helpful if you actually posted those errors-  that will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach random properties to DOM elements :

```
function testPro(){
    var test = 'init'; 

    link.href         = '#';
    link.innerHTML   += 'test value';
    link.onclick      = onClick;
    link.onmouseover  = onHover;
    link.onmouseout   = hoverOut;  
    link.test         = test;
}

function onHover(){
    alert(this.test);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6fWVK/)

Comment: I ended it up using your solution. quick and easy. Tyvm

Answer (score 3):

Use a small function expression that takes the event argument and passes it together with the `test` value to `onHover`:

```
var test = …;
link.onclick = function(event) {
    return onHover(test, event);
};

// somewhere else (on a higher scope than `test`)
function onHover(arg) {
    alert(arg);
}
```

Comment: thanks Bergi, but my onclick already return other variable. +1

Comment: I was a little confused when you said you wanted to call `onHover` with a variable when the user *clicks* the button… Probably you will need to adapt it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like:

```
function makeClickHandler(arg) {
  return function (event) {
    alert(arg);
  }
}

link1.onclick = makeClickHandler('arg1');
link2.onclick = makeClickHandler('arg2');
// ...
```

To increment a variable for that button, you could write a handler something like this:

```
function makeClickHandler() {
  var i = 0;
  return function (event) {
    alert(++i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` variable defined in scope of `testPro` function and can't be used directly by `onHover` function called in global scope. You have several options to solve this issue:

Add `test` variable to the closure of event handler

```
function testPro() {
    ...
    var test = 'init';
    ...
    link.onmouseover = function() { return onHover(test); };
    ...
}

function onHover(test) {
    alert(test);
}
```

or put `test` variable to some globally accessible namespace

```
var globals = { test: null };

function testPro() {
    ...
    globals.test = 'init';
    ...
    link.onmouseover  = onHover;
    ...
}

function onHover() {
    alert(globals.test);
}
```

or bind callback execution to some object containing `test`

```
function testPro() {
    ...
    var scope = { test: 'init' };
    ...
    link.onmouseover  = onHover.bind(scope);
    ...
}

function onHover() {
    alert(this.test);
}
```

or add custom data attribute to DOM element

```
function testPro() {
    ...
    link.setAttribute('data-test','init');
    ...
    link.onmouseover  = onHover;
    ...
}

function onHover() {
    alert(this.getAttribute('data-test'));
}
```

Comment: And `(function(test) { return onHover; }(test))` is good for… what?

Answer (score 0):

you can reevaluate the function in the scope of execution to grab the closures, but i would recommend using a different methods, as eval() is not without caveats.

so, even though i'd try to talk you out of it, this DOES do what you asked for with minimal re-factoring:

```
function testPro(){

    var test = 'init';  //the test can only be init here...

    link.href         = '#';
    link.innerHTML   += 'test value';
    link.onclick      = eval( "0||"+ onClick);

}

function onClick(){
   alert(test);
}

link={};
testPro();
link.onclick(); //shows "init"...
```

Comment: `eval` is, in any case, not a solution for this problem.